# How to filter google places autocomplete suggestions?

Tags: javascript, google-places-autocomplete

how to make google autocomplete only suggest places that have zip code and house number? I want to be able to pick only a house with zip code.

What i've tried:

```
const autocompleteConfig = {
    componentRestrictions: { country: {{country}} },
    types: ['address'],
};

const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete({{element}}, autocompleteConfig);
```

The problem with the result that i am getting - some suggestions dont have zip code or house number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google places service should be used.

```
const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement);
const placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement);
```

First get autocomplete predictions:

```
placesService.getPlacePredictions({input: 'your place string'})
```

Then get place zip and house_number of every prediction

```
placesService.getDetails({placeId: placeIdFromPrediction})
```

Then filter suggestions.